# iPhone 4s shutdown problem

Tags: iphone, shutdown

I have a iPhone 4s as soon it reaches 30% or Lower it goes off anytime sometime immediately and sometime at 20% what should I do

Comment: sounds like the battery is EOL

Answer (score 2):

that's quite simple!! That means you need a new battery...

The % indication is not always most accurate, specially on older batteries.

....when your iPhone automatically shut down yet the usage indicates that you still have about 8 or 11 percent. that means your battery is dead or almost,not to mention your iPhone shut down while it indicated it still have about 20 or 30 percent!!!

I had that experience, I just replace my iPhone 4s battery these days since I found the same problem happened on my phone, it automatically shut down yet it says it still has about 11 percent of battery

Comment: is there a way to verify your claim before spending money on new battery?

Comment: of course!! it's obviously, when your iPhone automatically shut down yet the usage indicates that you still have about 8 or 11 percent. that means your battery is dead or almost,not to mention your iPhone shut down while it indicated it still have about 20 or 30 percent!!! Take myself for instance, i just replace my iPhone 4s battery these days since i found the same problem happened on my phone, it automatically shut down yet it says it still has about 11 percent of battery...

Comment: You can go buy the battery, don't go directly to the Apple store to pay a huge amount of money to buy a new one, there're many youtube videos to show you hoe you can do it yourself!! Or maybe you're not confident in your skills, you can still find many people to help you with the battery!! hope this advice can help you!!

Comment: As a former Apple Store Family Room Specialist (iPhone Genius) I can verify that unexpected power off when the battery is running low is typically a failed battery.